# openni_node doesnt work

Tags: openni-kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried next follows.

0. ubuntu 10.04LTS (working on VMware)
1. ROS Diamondback Fully install
2. Openni_Kinect install
3. https://openslam.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/data/svn/rgbdslam/trunk/README

but openni_node process has died ;(

what can i do for make sure?

> juno@ubuntu:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks$  roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch

```
... logging to /home/juno/.ros/log/d7465c3e-880a-11e0-b474-000c2902ad72/roslaunch-ubuntu-24377.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:54579/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_node1/use_indices
 * /openni_node1/depth_registration
 * /openni_node1/image_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_mode
 * /openni_node1/debayering
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
 * /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
 * /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/image_mode
 * /openni_node1/shift_offset
 * /openni_node1/device_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
  /
    openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
    kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    rgbdslam (rgbdslam/rgbdslam)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [24391]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to d7465c3e-880a-11e0-b474-000c2902ad72
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [24404]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [24407]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [24408]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [24409]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [24410]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [24411]
process[rgbdslam-7]: started with pid [24412]
[ INFO] [1306464102.576724141]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1306464102.577206931]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:04 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00363909966114A'
[ INFO] [1306464102.580068124]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1306464108.049142005]: [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:4 with serial number 'A00363909966114A'
[ INFO] [1306464108.078700920]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1306464108.080752179]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame' 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startImageStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-openni-kinect-0.1.3/debian/ros-diamondback-openni-kinect/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 159 : starting image stream failed. Reason: Xiron OS got an event timeout!
[openni_node1-2] process has died [pid 24407, exit code -6].
log files: /home/juno/.ros/log/d7465c3e-880a-11e0-b474-000c2902ad72/openni_node1-2*.log
```

> juno@ubuntu:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks$
> ls common
> hogman_minimal           robot_model
> common_msgs
> image_common             ros_comm
> common_tutorials
> image_pipeline           ros_tutorials
> diagnostics
> image_transport_plugins  rx
> diagnostics_monitors
> laser_pipeline
> simulator_gazebo documentation
> navigation
> simulator_stage driver_common
> openni_kinect            slam_gmapping
> executive_smach
> perception_pcl           vision_opencv
> executive_smach_visualization
> perception_pcl_addons    visualization
> geometry
> physics_ode
> visualization_common
> geometry_tutorials
> rgbdslam
> visualization_tutorials

what should i do for launch RGBDSLAM?

***Juno, Yoon ( juno@robot.re.kr )***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10078/openni_node-doesnt-work/) by [Juno](https://answers.ros.org/users/603/juno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-31**:
Could you please retitle this question to something like Openni_node not working in VM? That way others with the same problem will be more likely to see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenNI doesn't work in VMWare. No, I don't know why, but you're the third person (off the top of my head) to have this problem, and no solution is extant. The older (libfreenect-based) kinect drivers should work; if you do manual calibration, you'll end up in roughly the same place OpenNI gets you.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-05-31**:
Do you mean you installed in on a bare-metal linux, rather than in a virtual machine?

**Comment by [Juno](https://answers.ros.org/users/603/juno/) on 2011-05-31**:
I try to Install on my laptop again but I had same problem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> what():  virtual void
> openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startImageStream()
> @
> /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-openni-kinect-0.1.3/debian/ros-diamondback-openni-kinect/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp
> @ 159 : starting image stream failed.
> Reason: Xiron OS got an event timeout!

This is a problem in the openni driver, not in rgbdslam!
Unfortunately therefore I have no solution to offer.
Is your kinect plugged in? What do the commands `dmesg|tail` and `lsusb` output after you plugged it in?

Readable answer:

```
[ 111.869697] hub 2-1.5:1.0: 3 ports detected 
[ 112.815956] usb 2-1.5.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9 
[ 114.350696] usb 2-1.5.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 10 
[ 115.885492] usb 2-1.5.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 11

Bus 002 Device 011: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:219c Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp.
```

That seems fine, so I guess it is Mac's answer then

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juno](https://answers.ros.org/users/603/juno/) on 2011-05-30**:
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp.
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp.
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp.
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:219c Broadcom Corp.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp.

**Comment by [Juno](https://answers.ros.org/users/603/juno/) on 2011-05-30**:
[  111.869697] hub 2-1.5:1.0: 3 ports detected
[  112.815956] usb 2-1.5.2: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9
[  114.350696] usb 2-1.5.1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 10
[  115.885492] usb 2-1.5.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 11